# how to subtract 2 query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 query. first is

```
SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-03-01') <= 5 THEN 5 -  
WEEKDAY('2017-03-01') ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') <= 5 THEN
WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') + 1 ELSE 5 END + (DATEDIFF('2017-03-03', 
'2017-03-01') + 1 - (7 - WEEKDAY('2017-03-01')) - (WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') + 
1)) DIV 7 * 5 AS w_d
```

an output of that query is

```
w_k
 3
```

and the 2nd one is

```
  SELECT count(*) FROM attendence WHERE eid=1 and login < ('2017-03-03' + interval 1 day ) AND login >= '2017-03-01' .
```

an output of that query count(*)

```
3
```

and I want to subtract query1 - 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Select (
    (SELECT CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-03-01') <= 5 THEN 5 - WEEKDAY('2017-03-01') ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') <= 5 THEN WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') + 1 ELSE 5 END + (DATEDIFF('2017-03-03', '2017-03-01') + 1 - (7 - WEEKDAY('2017-03-01')) - (WEEKDAY('2017-03-03') + 1)) DIV 7 * 5) - 
(SELECT count() FROM attendence WHERE eid=1 and login < ('2017-03-03' + interval 1 day ) AND login >= '2017-03-01')) AS w_d
```

Comment: @Mayur Did this Solve your issue?

Comment: Hi sir, is it possible, combined or join above 2 query and show a different output of both of them?  and similar column of both tables is [ id ]. if possible then can u give me hint about the query. Thank You in Advanced.

Comment: Could you explain what you need with output so that i will directly got your point.

Comment: I have 4 unrelated query and I want to combine this and get output in tabular format.plz, give me hint for that.

Comment: I think you want to `Union` . for this please see below link
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html